# Calculate time between time in python and time in mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

`

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now ()
tgl = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
y = now.strftime ('%H:%M:%S')
print(y)
>>> 20:01:10

crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM tblsolar WHERE tanggal LIKE '%s' AND id LIKE '1001' ;" % (tgl))
res = crsr.fetchall()
for i in res:
    z = i[9]
print(z)
>>>  8:09:34
```

```
can someone help me in this situation
i want to calculate between z and y (time duration)
x = y - z
```

any help thank you..

i have try
`

```
import datetime as dt
start_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S')
end_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(y, '%H:%M:%S')
diff = (end_dt - start_dt)
print(diff)
```

> > > strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.timedelta`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got the answer :)

```
    import datetime as dt
    start_dt = x
    end_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(y, '%H:%M:%S')
    diff = (end_dt - start_dt)
    print(diff.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

thank @Tim Biegeleisen for correction the code
thank NicoDorn for the input

Comment: I see you're new here -- you can mark any one of the answers as correct, even your own, so the next person that comes along can learn, too!  Add a checkmark next to the best one.

Answer (score 2):

I reckon that the `%s` placeholder should appear alone and outside single quotes:

```py
sql = "SELECT * FROM tblsolar WHERE tanggal = %s AND id = '1001'"
crsr.execute(sql, (tgl,))
res = crsr.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 2):

you mean this SQL Syntax?

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'HH:mm:ss') as DT
```

This should give you the same as the python time with format '%H%M%S'